# skak package error

Tags: skak

I am using TeXworks in MikTex portable 2.9

when I use the following code, I get the error message

```
Couldn't find `SkakNew-Diagr.cfg'

miktex-maketfm: No creation rule for font SkakNew-Diagram.
! Font LSB/skaknew/m/n/20=SkakNew-Diagram at 20.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) 
file not found.
```

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{skak}

\begin{document}
\section*{Chess}

\newgame
\mainline{1.e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3.Bb5}
\[ \showboard \]
\mainline{3...a6} Rarely used these days,
\variation{3...Nf6} is more in fashion since blah blah... \\
\mainline{4.Ba4}
\[ \showboard \]

\end{document}
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: Install with the package manager the skaknew package.

Comment: I downloaded the skaknew package; how to use it with TeXworks in MikTex portable 2.9

Comment: miktex portable has also a package manager. Start `miktex-portable.cmd` to get the little tray menu and then start the package manager.  https://miktex.org/portable

Comment: When I tried to install skaknew, I got the following error message: MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: The remote package repository is not registered. You have to choose another repository.

Comment: And did you try to choose another repository? If not why not?

Comment: I do not know how to choose another repository

Comment: Find it out. I really don't have the time to guide you to obvious menu entries.